# Magento2 error does not have corresponding setter in class "Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationExtensionInterface"

Tags: magento2

I have added custom filed in quote and order table,
when ever i want to save i get

Property "MetroTimeSlot" does not have corresponding setter in class "Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationExtensionInterface"

i have already added metro_time_slot in extension_attributes.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface">
    <attribute code="metro_time_slot" type="string"/>
</extension_attributes>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the same issue by removing files from [magento root]/var/generation/ folder.

Comment: Yes this was solved by removing generation files

Answer (score 1):

how do you pass the attribute in the request? It should be

```
{
    ...
    extension_attributes: {
         metro_time_slot: "value"
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it is same

extension_attributes:{                  
     metro_time_slot: $('[name="metro_time_slot"]').val()
}